# Time Complexity: While loop with nested for Loop[java]

Tags: java, time-complexity

So I just started learning time complexity and I have somewhat of an "okayish" grasp on it however I'm a little confused on how to go about this code segment.
I have read other posts but I just have a hard time grasping things unless someone butchers what I have to say. Kind of like a slap in the face.

```
public int example(int[] array) {

    int result = 15;
    int i = array.length;

    while(i > 1)
    {
      for(int x = 0; x < array.length;x++)
      {
        result+= 1;
        result+=2*array[x];
      }
      i = i/2; 
    }
return result;
}
```

Okay so I'm only counting arithmetic operations.
From what I believe, correct me if I'm wrong(probably am),

**x++** happens n times.

**result+= 1** happens n times.

**result +=3 * array[x]** happens 2n times

All for a total of **4n** times

and **i = i/2** happens **logn** times

So would the right equation be **4nlogn**??

Comment: Why do you think the second statement in the loop would execute twice as many times as the one before it?

Comment: I assumed because 2 arithmetic operations are happening but i guess it just happens n times aswell?

Comment: I see your logic now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track with `4n*log(n)`. However, note that for big O time complexity, constants are removed, so this would be `O(n*log(n))`.

Constants are removed because of the big O definition: `f(x)` is `O(g(x))` if `f(z) <= c*g(z)` for all `z` > some number. The key here is the `c` which can be any constant. Even if your `f(x)` is `100x` you could still have `c=200` and `g(x)` would still be greater.

As a side note, since we can factor out constants, you don't have to count EVERY operation when calculating big O time complexity. You need only look at the loops. One happens `n` times, the other `log(n)` times. So it is `O(n*log(n))`. The code could perform 1000 operations inside each loop, or it could perform 2. Because constants are factored out of our big O equation, that number doesn't matter. Only the number and nature of the loops does.

Comment: how is result+=2*array[x] is 2n times instead of n times?